# how to use swig-extras from command line

Tags: swig-template

I've installed [swig-extras](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig-extras) via npm package manager, because I need new filters.

I'm compiling my templates using command-line interface

```
$ swig render ./index.html -j ./index.json
```

I try to implement truncate filter and I don't know how to change my command to implement swig-extras filters.

Answer (score 0):

Once again I answered myself

> C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\swig\bin\swig.js

you have to add two lines

```
extras = require('../../swig-extras');
extras.useFilter(swig, 'truncate');
```

inside

```
var swig =
```